# How to define given conditions related to generators of groups on GAP

Tags: group-theory, cyclic-groups, group-isomorphism, group-presentation, gap

> Given $n,m,p,q$ natural numbers, such that $m,p,q < n.$ Find all natural numbers $r,s,t,a,b,c$ such that $p<r<n, q<a<n, s<m, b<m, t<a, c<r$ and the abelian group with presentation
>
> $$G=\langle x,y,z\mid x^m=y^pz^q, y^r=x^sz^t, z^a=x^by^c\rangle$$
>
> is isomorphic to the cyclic group $\Bbb Z_n$.

I tried for values $r =3, c=1, s=1, t=1, a=4, b=1$ but I don't know how to add all given conditions on GAP and to get final answer

```
gap> F:=FreeGroup("x","y","z");
<free group on the generators [ x, y, z ]>
gap> x:=F.1; y:=F.2; z:=F.3;
x
y
z
gap> G:=F/[x*y*(y*x)^-1,x*z*(z*x)^-1,y*z*(z*y)^-1,x^23*z^-3*y^-2, y^3*x^-1*z^-1,z^4*y^-1*x^-1];
<fp group on the generators [ x, y, z ]>
gap> Size(G);
231
```

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: I think this can be done by starting a `for . . . do . . . od;` to run over values of n in some domain, then do the same for each of the values, defining a function to define $G$ as you have done in terms of those variables, then printing `IsCyclic(G)` together with the values of those variables.

Comment: I think a much better approach is to put the relations into an integer matrix and compute the Smith normal form... This way you can easily solve it by hand and generally, instead of trying just a finite set of examples in GAP...

Comment: +_1 on SNF. In particular, note that if you use a presentation you must add relators that force abelian.